# Extract number from string [{"server_result":"101"}] in java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string that got from server (in android application) such as

```
[{"server_result":"101"}]
```

I want to use java to extract as `101` information. I tried to use String.replace() but it did not work

Thanks

Comment: this is JSON fromet..

Comment: Yes. But it is just small string. I want to use string class to replace it. I don't want to use so much lib

Comment: I think No any lib are use to call JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got a string containing that information, `replace()` should work fine!

```
String s = "[{\"server_result\":\"101\"}]";
s = s.replace("101", "somethingToReplace");
```

You have probably just forgotten to assign the value of `replace()` to the string!

**EDIT:**

Since you want to retrieve the number out of the string you can either use a regex, or you can extract it manually (when the string always has the same form):

```
String s = "[{\"server_result\":\"101\"}]";
String number = s.substring(s.indexOf(":")+2, s.length()-3);
```

But i would suggest using a regex as it will be a lot more readable!!

Answer (score 2):

That's obvious **JSON**. Use this :

```
string = "[{\"server_result\":\"101\"}]";
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0); 

str = obj.getString("server_result"); // str == "101"
```

If you don't wanna use JSON, consider this:

```
string = "[{\"server_result\":\"101\"}]";
String digitsOnly= string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); // digitsOnly == "101"
```

It shall remove all non digit characters from your string.

Comment: Thank. But  I don't like use JSON

Answer (score 2):

This is A JSON format.. Server Alwayes Return In Json Fromat.
use this easy way to find number..

```
string = "[{"server_result":"101"}]";
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);

str = obj.getString("server_result"); // str == "101"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a json then you have to do it quik and a litte dirty:

```
String serverString = "[{\"server_result\":\"101\"}]";
String[] splittedString = serverString.split(":"); //split 
splittedString[1] = splittedString[1].replace("\"", "").replace("}", "").replace("]", ""); //remove unnecessary chars
int i = Integer.parseInt(splittedString[1]); //try to parse to int
System.out.println(i);  //print it
```